# Setting a UIButton as selected

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my app, when a button is pressed n Custom `imagePicker` appears, it contains my images in `NSDocumentDirectory`, what I want is when I select an image it will either: HIDE, REMOVE, SET as SELECTED, or anything that will considered it selected.

What I have TRIED doing, is assign an integer to it, so the next time I present the `imagePicker` it will do either of the above, still, No luck.

Can you please suggest how can I solve my problem, or any suggestions. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Create view
    UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*140+24, row*150+10, 100, 100);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 


        [view addSubview:button];

        if (column == 6) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, (row+1) * 150 + 10)];
    self.view = view;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Here is where I tried in setting it selected:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger selectedImage = [prefs integerForKey:@"selected"];
    if ( selectedImage ){
        [myButton removeFromSuperview];
        [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [myButton setSelected:YES];
        [myButton setHidden:YES];
        [myButton setHighlighted:YES];
        myButton.selected = YES;
    }      
}
```

WHEN CLICKED:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    self.myButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.selectedImage = [_images objectAtIndex:myButton.tag];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:myButton.tag forKey:@"selected"];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Calling the `imagePicker`:

```
- (IBAction)chooseCustomImageTapped:(id)sender {
    _imagePicker1 = [[CustomImagePicker alloc] init];
    _imagePicker1.title = @"Choose Custom Image";
   for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]]; 
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [_imagePicker1 addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

        } 
    } 

     [self presentModalViewController:_imagePicker1 animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: what is myButton in viewDidAppear? u suppose to get this button according to the selectedImage no?

Comment: no just the integer, my button is the button I instantiate

Comment: If I understand right, your CustomImagePicker has a grid of buttons, each button with an image. So in viewDidAppear u should get the index of the selected button and get the relevant button (that u already created in viewDidLoad), why are u creating a new button?

Comment: i instantiate it so I can use it in viewDidAppear, i just want to when it is selected, the next time i pop the picker it will still preview as selected that's why i have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this to change button to look selected:

```
- (void)turnButtonToSelected
{
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

But I must say I didn't understand what is this button, where do u place it?
Is this one of the buttons on the grid?

Put this in viewDidAppear instead of your code

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger selectedImage = [prefs integerForKey:@"selected"];
    if ( selectedImage ){
        for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && subview.tag == selectedImage) {
                [self turnButtonToSelected];
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: But in viewDidLoad u create all the buttons and place them in the view, then in viewDidAppear u create a new button and place it in the same place where u have a button already ??(the button that u created in viewDidLoad)

Comment: i just want to when it is selected, the next time i pop the picker it will still preview as selected that's why i have done that. every time i pop the picker i want to shoe that it is selected